# How to get CLPlacemark from Place

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, core-location, clgeocoder

I have a place name like `" Tirur,keala,India"` getting from Google API

I want to get the  `CLPlacemark`, getting error when try to get directly from google api,
So that I am trying to get like this,

When I try using  `" Kerala "` I can get exact placemark,

If I try `" Tirur "` getting some incorrect place, 
So, How can I search by using both  `"Tirur,keala"`

Here is my code,

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:@"Tirur" completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);

            } else {
                CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
                            placemark.location.coordinate.latitude; will returns latitude
                             placemark.location.coordinate.longitude; will returns longitude
            }
        }];
```